# Storing json vs Object vs Map in Hazelcast.

Tags: hazelcast

I am new to `Hazelcast` and would appreciate your thoughts on the below.

**Use case :** I have a database `table CUSTOMER (id, firstname, lastname,age)` , and would like to store it in a distributed map. There would be need to query(may be predicate) the collection and general get/put operations. There will be somewhere around a million records and I have 2 nodes at my disposal.

What would the best approach be keeping performance and memory in mind.

1.Store the records as Map of Maps ; IMap> ; where the keys in the inner map are the column names

Or

2.Store the records as json;  `IMap<String,String> Ex: [ "123" : { "id" : "123", "firstname" : "john", "lastname" : "Deer", "age" : "25" }]`

Or

3.Create a Customer DTO and store it in IMap

Thanks

Comment: Please try to prevent double postings of the same questions in multiple locations, it makes it hard to answer those because answers get fragmented!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last option using an Entity class is preferred, however if you expect the object often to be changed JSON might be preferable for schemaless (since you're talking about a database table I guess you don't need that).

Btw your first option is not working since IMap itself is not serializable. You could do IMap> but the problem with this approach is that the inner map needs to be completely deserialized on every get which will kill you're performance ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  If I use the 1st approach  IMap<String,  Map<String,  String>> Or the last approach IMap<String, Customer>, deserialization is performed on every get operation. 
The advantage I could get out of using IMap<String,Customer> is that I will have the flexibility to provide my version of serialization/Externalization, Is this understanding right ?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You can use java.io.Serializable, java.io.Externalizable, com.hazelcast.core.DataSerializable or for max speed / bytesize com.hazelcast.core.IdentifiedDataSerializable :)